# Removing unwanted '\n'

Tags: python

I'm writing a program that is to read some indata from a text file. The data is a mix of strings and integers. A typical file might look like this:

```
Kiruna
setaim=0
23
34
20
1
1
20
```

I read the file with

```
f = open(path,'r')
content = f.readlines()
```

If I print the content list, I get

```
['Kiruna\n', 'setaim=0\n', '23\n', '34\n', '20\n', '1\n', '1\n', '20\n']
```

When I want to use the string in the first element the '\n' causes problems, and I want it removed. I have checked some other threads that suggest that I should use the methods .strip() or .rstrip() I've tried

```
content[0].rstrip('\n')
```

and

```
content[0]=content[0].rstrip('\n')
```

but all I get is the error

```
"TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'"
```

What do I do?

Comment: You probably did `content = f.readlines` by mistake; this will make `content` point to the _function_ readlines, instead of the result of the function call.

Comment: you can use x=f.read().Then y=x.split("\n")

Comment: Is there a problem with `content = f. readlines()`? I tried other methods but they didn't wotk better.

Answer (score 6):

```
with open(path,'r') as f:
    content = [line.rstrip() for line in f] #this should remove all "\n"
print content
```

**output:**

```
['Kiruna', 'setaim=0', '23', '34', '20', '1', '1', '20']
```

Comment: Might I suggest the `with open(path, 'r') as f:` syntax. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
content = [x.rstrip() for x in f] # remove all the new lines when file is read
```

Better to use `with` to open your files, it closes them automatically:

```
with open(path,'r') as f:
    content = [x.rstrip() for x in f]
```

Answer (score 0):

`readlines` returns an iterator, not a list, and you can therefore not use index to get an element.
Iterate over the iterator with i.e. a list comprehension and it works.

```
content = [x.rstrip() for x in f]
```